# My 1998 f150 4.6 only blows out lukewarm air

Tags: ford

My 1998 f150 4.6 heater only blows out lukewarm air. I have replaced the radiator and thermostat. I also have flushed out the heater core. Any ideals what to do to get hot air...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [1997 ford f150 heater not working properly](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/8825/1997-ford-f150-heater-not-working-properly). This is a common problem with these vehicles.